# Inactivity-based auto logout from all sessions

Tags: bash, logout

I want to be able to logout inactive sessions on my webserver.
I have done this like so:

```
13. Restrict idle users. Timeout after a certain pre-defined amount of time.
a. In the directory /etc/profile.d:
i. Create a file called autologout.sh and add the following lines:
TMOUT=300
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT
This sets autologout settings for the bash shell.
ii. Create a file called autologout.csh and add the following lines:
set -r autologout 5
iii. Add execute privileges to both files with: sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/autologout.*
```

I notice that the above lines log the user out only from the current active account and not terminate the session completely.
eg.) If I sudo-ed to root, I am logged out of root and returned to my user account.

Can I log the user out completely? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many years ago, I used to use a program called `timeoutd` to do exactly this.  It seems to have vanished from `debian` since I last used it (or maybe it was never in debian and I compiled it myself - I can't remember, I last used it in the mid-1990s).

Anyway, I found a copy of it at:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/timeoutd

It is configurable with an `/etc/timeouts` file.  You can find the man page in the package, with the source, or at 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man8/timeoutd.8.html

Comment: Thanks! This fits my use case beautifully. However, I am not allowed to compile any source etc. on the machine. I am marking this as correct.

Comment: what distro are you using?  it may already be packaged for it.  otherwise you could compile your own package on another machine, then it's just a single, simple install with your package manager (`dpkg` or `rpm` or whatever)

Comment: I am using Centos7. I checked the repos with `sudo yum search timeout*` and did not find anything. Is there anything else I should look for? The `rpm` option sounds good. I might try that.